# What other rules are there in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I'm reading Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories.

> 1. a set $A$, called the *domain* of the map;
> 2. a set $B$, called the *codomain* of the map;
> 3. a rule assigning to each element $a$ in the domain, an element $b$ in the codomain.

This is almost the same I saw in the calculus books and I got curious with something: This rule is always an expression in which there's a substitution in it's values, it seems everything is reduced to a function, are there other kinds of rules? Are the rules that can't be reduced to functions? Until now, I guess I'm aware only about the functions and mappings.

Comment: Nice title for a book. Hard to know how Euler, Gauss, Hilbert, almost all Fields medal winners managed without.

Comment: Are you trolling me?

Comment: This is the definition of function, with a clarification: "a rule assigning to each element a in the domain, an <b>unique</b> element b in the codomain.

Comment: I am not sure what trolling means. I am objecting to the author's arrogation of "conceptual" to his branch of mathematics. Absolutely nothing to do with you.

Comment: @dwarandae Yes. Btw, `**bold**`.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: the fact that categories are purely intensionally defined, as opposed to the extensional foundations of ZF-style set theory, gives a meaning to the use of "conceptual" you may be missing.  Sets may be reasoned about as concrete collections, whereas reasoning in categories is purely about the definitional diagrams, independent of concrete realisation.  The name isn't meant to be arrogant.  It's about intensional reasoning.

Comment: @ex0du5: The author’s intention does not make this use of *conceptual* any less ambiguous and unhelpful, or any more palatable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  I'm not sure if you're punning or misunderstood.  I said "intensional" with an s.  It's not the same as "intentional", though they are related.  It's not ambiguous.  It's why Dana Scott used closed-cartesion categories as a foundation for computational semantics.  It's a programme that Lawvere widely championed.  It's a well-defined logical distinction.  Alonzo Church, for instance, made an intensional calculus for studying the logic of definitional meaning.

Comment: @ex0du5: I’m perfectly well aware of the difference between *intensional* and *intentional*. I was mildly amused that the word that I wanted was a homophone of one that you’d used, but I was not deliberately punning. I have no idea what the rest of your comment is about, since the word that I was talking about is obviously *conceptual*, the same one to which André took exception.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I'm sorry, I guess I didn't explain the full relation.  Typically, intensional resoning is about the *signified* of a symbol, extensional is about the *referent* of a symbol.  The signified is the concept of a symbol, the referent is the object.  This is the standard concept/object distinction in logic.  Wikipedia describes this somewhat: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intension

Comment: As does Merriam-Webster: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/signified

Comment: @ex0du5: I know all of this. I do not see that it mitigates the problems with this use of *conceptual*. I still consider the title apt both to mislead and to offend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common historical trend to unnecessarily assume that any function must be given by a formula of some sort. In the modern approach to mathematics this is absolutely not the case. The 'rule' in the explanation above of how to think of functions does not need to be a formula or even potentially expressible as one.

More rigorously, a function $f:A\to B$ is a certain relation, that is a subset of $A\times B$. The cardinality of all functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is greater than the cardinality of expressions of possible formulas and so there are more functions than there are formulas describing functions.

It should be noted that some debate on the meaning of 'function' in calculus during the years of the formation of the subject existed. Things that today we accept as functions, such as the Dirichlet function and Bolzano's or Weiestrass' nowhere differentiable continuous functions, were not always considered functions.

So, the use of the word 'rule' in your question is just a heuristic or mnemonic or intuitive concept to talk about what functions are in some intuitive plane. The definition of function employed today is set-theoretic and leaves no room for ambiguities (unless you consider the axiom of choice an ambiguity) or, I'm afraid, for your question.